# IE 9 ignoring keydown event on initial load

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing a strange behaviour, hopefully someone out there can explain this.

I have keypress event capturing any keys pressed on the screen.  If 'P' is hit, expands a section that does a focus() and select() on an input field.

The field has a keydown() event that only allows numeric characters.

So when I am on the main screen and hit 'P', the section expands as it should, but the field now has a 'P' in it.  ***This only occurs in IE9.***

Strangely enough, the keydown() event must kick in after the 'P' is put in there, because if I try to enter 'P' into the field, I am not allowed.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: I don't think you need a focus() if you do a select(), since it focuses the field by selecting the text.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a global keydown, and then a keypress on the INPUT, not the other way around? That would make more sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the keydown() event must kick in*"?

Comment: Thanks Sime, the focus(), select() is legacy existing code, what I mean by the keydown() event kicking in is that after the section shows, I am no longer allowed to enter 'P'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, I wasn't returning false on the keypress event, once I did that, no more input was sent to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change `keypress` with `keyup`? I think that it is IE bubbling or propagation bug.

Comment: Thanks Tamlyn, I'll take a look and try this.

Comment: Sorry Tamlyn, the "keyup" event could not be bound to the input with JQuery in IE9.

Comment: It should be. Can you show some code? It could help understanding your problem ;)